# Windows 10 Namespace Extension - OpenFileDialog and the temporary folder

Tags: c++, explorer, file-browser, shell-namespace-extension

For a little side project I've been working on a namespace extension to view and modify a custom archive format straight from windows explorer. This is working fine: I can browse the archive, modify it etc., but I've run into a little stumbling block when it comes to the windows file browser and how it handles opening files straight from the archive.

For whatever reason, when opening a file from the archive it puts a copy in the windows Cache folder (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE). It also changes the filename by appending "[]". I've noticed that the windows zip archive handling has the same behaviour. This is causing issues for an application that I want to allow to select files straight from the archive, since it copies the file in there without any sub-folder information and I need to know the relative path of the selected file (relative to the archive).

So my questions are:

1. Can I override this temporary file path somehow/somewhere, so that I have full control over where this temporary file is placed and how it's named?
2. Barring 1, is there a way for me to get the original path from the file(browser)? (using WPF for the client application)

Comment: Hello, did you ever get a working solution for this? My company have just run into the same issue and can't see a way to fix it. Thanks.